# npm ERR! command sh -c node install.mjs

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I'm having a problem to install npm in project which I cloned from git. Even I having package.json file in my folder.

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/deeps/Documents/code/train/NODE-api/node_modules/puppeteer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.mjs

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/deeps/.npm/_logs/2024-03-30T06_48_33_241Z-debug-0.log
```

I cleared all caches and even forcefully reinstalled npm, but I am still experiencing the same issue with npm install.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.